# Ocaml match pattern combination

Tags: ocaml

I have been struggling with this for sometime now. I have a match pattern that could be a combination. For example in the code below:

```
let  processoperatorchange t2s proc op op2=
  let rec poc p = match p with
    | Zero ->  "0"
    | In(chan, var, _, p, _) -> chan^"("^var^")"^op2^(poc p) 
    | Out(chan, value, p, _) -> chan^"<"^(v2s value)^">"^op^(poc p)
```

It could be that `In` and `Out` occur in one instance. Is there a way I could say

```
let  processoperatorchange t2s proc op op2=
  let rec poc p = match p with
    | Zero ->  "0"
    **| In(chan, var, _, p, _) && Out(chan, value, p, _) -> chan^("^var^")"^op2^(poc p)** 
    | Out(chan, value, p, _) -> chan^"<"^(v2s value)^">"^op^(poc p)
```

Comment: I think you want or-patterns: `| In(c, v, _, p, _) | Out(c, v, p, _) -> ...`. Note that the variables have to have the same type in each case, which your code suggests may not be the case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but since my variables are different, this condition doesn't work for me. Thanks for this though

Comment: What do you mean when you say that they could occur in one instance?

Comment: My program will be taking inputs from the user and based on those inputs, I evaluate the case that matches. In some cases, the user could combine two cases such as "In" and "Out" or "In" and "Timer".

Comment: The variable p has to be either "In" or "Out". It can't be both, unless there is a type that combines the two.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I find your "in one instance" quite strange. Maybe you should add a constructor `InOut` and a constructor `InTimer`.

Comment: Ok, that gives me an idea. I will try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Elevating comment from Lhooq to an answer:

Maybe you should add a constructor `InOut` and a constructor `InTimer`.